# Android app stuck on sharing username from 1 activity to another but not getting it through SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Basically i want to use the email id from which user log in to store and use in any activity for fetching the data from server. Please help me.

First Activity *Sign_In*

```
public class Sign_In extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String LOGIN_URL="url";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL="email";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD="password";
public static final String LOGIN_SUCCESS="success";
public static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME="tech";
public static final String EMAIL_SHARED_PREF="email";
public static final String LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF="loggedin";
private EditText editTextEmail;
private EditText editTextPassword;
private Button BtnLogin;
private boolean loggedIn=false;

   @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign__in);

       editTextEmail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
      editTextPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
     BtnLogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    BtnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
         login();
    }
 });
}

   private void login() {
final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        if (response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(LOGIN_SUCCESS)){
                            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = Sign_In.this.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                            editor.putBoolean(LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, true);
                            editor.putString(EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, email);

                           editor.apply();

      Intent intent = new Intent(Sign_In.this, HomePage.class);
startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else {
Toast.makeText(Sign_In.this,"Invalid credentials",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new  Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override

                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                }){
            @Override
           protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws  AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> prams = new HashMap<>();
            prams.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
            prams.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);

            return prams;
        }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
    @Override
    protected  void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);
        if (loggedIn){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Sign_In.this, HomePage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Second Activity *HomePage*

```
import static in.borrowfunds.build30.Sign_In.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF;
import static in.borrowfunds.build30.Sign_In.SHARED_PREF_NAME;

public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
            AlertDialog.Builder alertbox=new AlertDialog.Builder(HomePage.this);
            alertbox.setTitle("You want to Exit?");
            alertbox.setCancelable(false);
            alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Sign_In.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            });
            alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
            alertbox.show();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode,event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_b) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), B.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), L.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_p) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), P.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_e) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), E.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_pr) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Pr.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
            SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();
            HomePage.this.finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Sign_In.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_email) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto","contact@hgdcsa.net",null));
            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Mail account not configured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you **retreive** the data, whatever it may be, you can use `SharedPreferences` to store and access it locally on the device:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
String pref = preferences.getString("preference_key", "default-username");
// if the pref isn't set, you can designate a default value
```

Any activity you want to access this data, you can call `preferences.getString` (or any type) to access what the user stored.

You can **store data** in the `SharedPreferences` by `edit` and `commit`ing changes:

```
preferences.edit().putString("preference_key", "username").commit();
```

Preferences come in **all kinds of types**, notably:

- `String`
- `int`
- `boolean`

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by myself, what a relief, was stuck on this for about 10 days.
Btw thanks for the anwers and i'm providing the solution for future purpose.

First Activity

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = Sign_In.this.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                            editor.putBoolean(LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, true);
                            editor.putString(EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, email);

                            editor.apply();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(Sign_In.this, HomePage.class);
                            intent.putExtra(EMAIL_SHARED_PREF,email);
                            startActivity(intent);
```

Second Activity

```
TextView email1;
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String email = sharedPreferences.getString(EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, "");

        email1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView18);
        email1.setText(email);
```